# Implementation of types, or abstraction ... Advantages and disadvantages

Tags: java, class, oop, types, diagram

I was talking with my fellow Java programmers, and came across a novice question, polemic and perhaps even silly, which unfortunately confuse me. In order for my question becomes understandable, I'll give a quick example here. Consider the following situation:

I have a car engine. Every engine is designed to work with one type of fuel (named combustible).

In this type of problem, I created a "Vehicle" class, which uses a "Engine" as a class field member, because every engine has properties and behaviors. Let's suppose that the car fuel container is part of the car engine, therefore, an engine knows how to fuel itself, and knows how to store it. With these things in mind, I sought to develop an "Engine" class (as said before), which has such properties. The problem is basically this. I get to be in doubt when I think of the following:

There are several types of car engines. Different engines have the same properties, but configured differently. Supposing that engine models do not suffer polymorphism, I got two different types of designs...

I will call this "model A":

[image]

And this, "model B":

[image]

Note that model A shows a concrete class "Engine", while model B demonstrates an abstract class "Engine" with it's implementations. **My question is what are the implications, advantages and disadvantages present among different types of models**.

I was always instructed by programmers, analysts, and database administrators to never tie data into programming code, and never limit a program to be recompiled (over and over), where only the recompilation offer results.

According to model B, a change in "engine market" and companies will always reflect a change of code. As a consequence, this will lead to creation of a new type of engine, its extension of the "Engine" class, its implementation, and compilation.

However, the model "A" shows that it is difficult to distribute the same engine for different vehicles, for example, with the same model. The creation of each new instance of an engine equal to another may require the same settings as necessary.

I see positives and negatives in both types of models, but I'm not sure of them. This situation proves to me that the addition of new types of things can perhaps lead to a bad road.

Although I want to have made ​​clear the example of engines and cars, I think this situation can be seen elsewhere. Thinking of another kind of example quickly ... if we have a "Fruit" class with subtypes "orange", "grape", "Etc." for each new fruit will we have to necessarily rewrite the program and recompile it? This does not tie up a program?

If I'm confusing something, please objectify it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

If different subtypes require different code to handle them, make them different subclasses. If different types differ only by the value of one or more fields, and you don't have to write any special code to handle any of those values differently, just make them all instances of a single concrete class.

If you don't need subclasses now, but you're worried that you might in the future, don't worry. If your requirements change so that you need subclasses in the future, you'll undoubtedly have to change your code in other ways anyway, so you'll have to recompile anyway.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer was enlightening. Indeed, if a project likely to change in the future, it will need to be recompiled anyway. But I think this is not the only issue. I think I am also concerned not only with the question of rebuilding, but with the amount of maintenance that will be performed on a program.

Comment: Possibly this is already obvious, but the part of the agile approach (and mine) to minimizing maintenance that is relevant here is to not write code until it's needed. Put another way, if you guess what you'll need, you're likely to guess incorrectly.

Comment: It's true. After all, one thing can become a project only when the business rules are collected. There is no point in adding things that are not in the project. Often we hear "keep your design dynamic enough that things are easily added later". But then we come to the point where you said, which makes no sense trying to guess what comes next, because it not only is not in the design but also may even undermine what we already have. I agree again with what you said. Thank you my friend.

Answer (score 0):

Unless a model is fundamentally flawed, in general, there are no positives or negatives worth talking too unless a context is provided. By context, I mean a set of requirements. A set of requirements will make model A the ideal one, and another would invalidate it completely (same for B.)

In the most general terms, model A's supposed disadvantage is that it models a concrete set of requirements. Namely that there are no requirements to extend the design. There will always be an engine with set-in-stone characteristics and capabilities. **The requirements must explicitly call for this.**

In some real cases, this would be the ideal model.

In another hypothetical, there could be a family of engines, some made out of aluminum, others with different allows. Others might have 'plug-in' ports to attach different electronics that are not required in the base model.

In such a case, then model B is the correct way to go (and model A would be a bad choice.)

So, again, a non-trivial discussion is hard to have without having requirements. Requirements on the business domain are what drives the most important characteristics of the domain model, which then drive the software and architecture related models.

ps.

Your model is mixing *volatile* state (`on` and possibly `name) with type/structural attributes (`combustible`,`capacity`, etc.)

Also, as you describe the problem, `fuel container` needs to be taken into account. But in reality, it is not part of engine. It is an `aggregate` (not a `composite` but an `aggregate`), one that is attached to the engine, but that does not depend on it. It can be replaced, swapped and/or destroyed independently of the engine (and vice versa).

Meaning, both the engine and the fuel container have different life cycles, even if both are joined into a working system. This would also call for a 'model B' type of system, for you can have engine specializations that can only be adapted to specific models of fuel containers.

As such, the `fuel()` method would be more appropriate for a `fuel container` entity, rather than for the `engine` entity.

My $0.02

Comment: Hmm .. That makes sense. However, even if the context (the problem itself, right?) requires that subtypes have different behavior (only) of their supertypes, this could be easily solved by encapsulating the required behavior, and configuring it at runtime, without the need of creating subtypes, is not it? For me, subtypes that differ only in their behavior can be configured by encapsulating behavior, without the need for recompilation. I would love your opinion, I'm really confused. And... For my curiosity, what do you mean by "My $ 0.02"?

Comment: If you add something more in your response about this, I will consider it correct.